# while loop output for multiple condition

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, conditional-statements

```
main()
{
    int i=0,j=0;
    while(i<5,j<10)
    {
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    printf("%d,%d,",i,j);
}
```

output: `10,10`

```
int main(){
    int x=2,y=2;
    while(x<=5,y<=3)
         printf("%d %d ",++x, ++y);
    return 0;        
}
```

output: `3 3 4 4`

In the first code how can output is coming as `10,10`? can anyone explain,but the output for the second code is `3344`, Are both running on different logic?

Comment: You need to use && rather than the expression separator operator.

Comment: Aka _comma_ `,` operator. This `while(x<=5,y<=3)` does not do what you think it does. This does this: `while(y<=3)`.

Comment: Raw N So,actually if we write while(a,b) it is while(b),this actually i want to know.

Comment: @MathsManiac That is correct.

Comment: The first snippet is not valid C code. Both should be `int main(void)`! And don't spam tags!

Comment: it is valid in code blocks @Olaf

Comment: @MathsManiac: Non sequitur! Code::Blocks is an IDE, not a compiler! And if your compiler does not complain, it is not standard compliant. Either use a modern compiler or use the correct option to set standard C! Implicit `int` return type is invalid since 18 years (C99)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People are suggesting him to use `&&` operator, but he wants an explanation for why he is getting `10 10` from Example 1 and `3 3 4 4` from Example 2. 
Yes both logic is different. in Example 1 the `while` loop iterates from 0 to 9 and at 10th value it quits(Hope you understood how comma-operator works from all the answers). That's why it prints `10 10` for `i` and `j`. and in Example 2 it starts from 2 one pre-increment and the value gets 3 condition is true. it loops one more time and at `j=4` it fails and `3 3 4 4` values get printed. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank u. @Vishwajeet Vishu

Comment: you could accept my answer :)

Answer (score 5):

What happens is that you are using the **comma operator** within the condition of the while.

**comma operator** works evaluating **all** operands but throwing the result away except for the last one.

Your while is equivalent to the following:

```
 while(j<10)
{
    i++;
    j++;
}
```

Take a look at this answer: [What does the comma operator , do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are using the comma operator in your `while` loop instead of the logical and. The expression `i<5,j<10` means: Perform statement `i<5` but throw away the result and then perform statement `j<10` which will be the result of the whole expression. So in the end the first part isn't used as a check in your `while` condition. The reason why it's different in your second case is because of the ordering of your statements.

What your probably meant was:

```
while(i<5 && j<10)
     // do your stuff
```

Now both conditions have to be true.

Answer (score 1):

You are coding in c++ not python-perl,  this:

```
while(x<=5,y<=3)
```

is equivalent to `while (y <= 3)`

please use the boolean operators like && or  ||

```
while(x<=5 && y<=3)
```

Answer (score 1):

In this snippet `i<5,j<10` you are using the [built-in comma operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator). What you need to use is [logical and](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical): `&&` or `and`, like this:

```
while (i < 5 and j < 10)
```

The built-in comma operator evaluates all of the operands and throws all but the last away.
The reason the second code works is because the limit of `y` is lower than that of `x` and the condition on `y` is the stop condition in the while-loop. Thus the loop is correctly stopped by the condition on `y`, since `while (x <= 5, y <= 3)` is equivalent to `while (y <= 3)`.

Answer (score 1):

In C, expressions separated by comma `,` are evaluated left to right (atleast on gcc) and the value of whole expression e:

```
e = e1, e2, .. , en;
```

is same as `en`. Thus all the expression e1, ... , en-1 are discarded. Thus they only have uses in producing side-effects or macros. Thus here `i<5, j<10` is essentially nothing but `j<10` and same in second case. Its just `while(y<=3)` because `x<=5, y<=3` always evaluates to `y<=3`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `while` loop to :

```
while(i<5 && j<10)
{
    i++;
    j++;
}
```

as you want *both* conditions to be true. Right now you are using the [comma operator](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_comma_operator.htm), which evaluates all the operands but only keeps the last result.